# TypeError: closeEvent() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to create a GUI which just prints a, b, c from another method. I want to keep this method separate from the class since it will go in another script. When I run it, it prints out the correct results; however, it is also giving an error. Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

def printStuff(a, b, c):
    print a, b, c

class Login(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        self.buttonLogin = QtGui.QPushButton('Print Stuff', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(lambda: self.closeEvent(a,b,c))
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.setGeometry(650,350,400,150)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 150)

    def closeEvent(self,a,b,c):
        printStuff(a,b,c)
        self.close()

def RunApp(a,b,c):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login(a,b,c)
    login.show()
    app.exec_()

RunApp('1','2','3')
```

Expected result: 1 2 3

Actual Result:1 2 3
TypeError: closeEvent() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)

Is this a false positive error? And how can I correct this?

Comment: The problem is `self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(lambda: self.closeEvent(a,b,c))`, so maybe the `lambda` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, there is no trace. all it says is "TypeError: closeEvent() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
1 2 3"

Comment: You don't get to pick how many arguments `closeEvent` takes; whatever calls `closeEvent` will only be providing a single argument.

Comment: @DavidCullen, remove lambda causes my GUI to call out printStuff when initiating, even if i don't click on the button

Comment: @J.D. Yeah, as we all have learned, `connect` expects a function that takes no parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving more parameters to the closeEvent where you connect your button. `closeEvent()` takes an QCloseEvent as an argument.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

def printStuff(a, b, c):
    print a, b, c

class Login(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.buttonLogin = QtGui.QPushButton('Print Stuff', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.closeGUI)
        self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.setGeometry(650,350,400,150)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 150)

    def closeGUI(self):
        printStuff(self.a,self.b,self.c)
        self.close()

def RunApp(a,b,c):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login(a,b,c)
    login.show()
    app.exec_()

RunApp('1','2','3')
```

Comment: Hi @Dress, although this eliminated the error, it is now producing the results twice now. Also, why is the event argument passed but not used?

Comment: ohhhhhhhh, that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @J.D. No problem, if it solved your question please upvote and mark as solved.